How to loop through sheets
I have a really simple script that's mapped to a custom menu:
function CollapseGroups() {
  
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().collapseAllRowGroups();
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().collapseAllColumnGroups();
 
}

It works flawlessly. But I want to now adapt it to run every night, over every sheet. I know the getActiveSheet() won't work with a time trigger because there won't be an active sheet.
When I try to getspreadsheet by id and loop through all the sheets the .CollapseAllRowGroups() errors out. I don't have the skills to work out what's wrong

Use Spreadsheet.getSheets() and Array.forEach(), like this:
'use strict';

/**
* Collapses row and column groups across all tabs in a spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Spreadsheet} ss Optional. The spreadsheet where to collapse all groups.
*/
function collapseAllGroupsInSpreadsheet(ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 28 August 2024
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78922864/13045193
  const actions = ['collapseAllRowGroups', 'collapseAllColumnGroups'];
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sheet => {
    actions.forEach(action => {
      try {
        sheet[action]();
      } catch (error) {
        ss.toast(error.message);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

To make the function run every night, create a time-driven trigger.
See Spreadsheet.getSheets() and Array.forEach().

To do something over all the sheets, first use SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getSheets() to get a collection of sheets, then iterate over them. There are many options for this. The below function uses Array.prototype.forEach
/**
 * @param {event} e Event object. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events
 */
function timeDriveHandler(e = { source: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() }){
  e.source.getAllSheets().forEach( sheet => {
     CollapseGroups(sheet)
  })
}

The below function is your function with a few changes:

Added a parameter with the active sheet as the default value.
Use the parameter instead of SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().
Includes a try..catch to prevent the script from iterating over all the sheets.

/**
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet A sheet. The default value is the active sheet.
 */
function CollapseGroups(sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()) {
  try {
     sheet.collapseAllRowGroups();
     sheet.collapseAllColumnGroups();
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('%s, %s', error.message, error.stack);
  }
}

Set your trigger to send the notifications immediately. You will get one daily message if you keep the default notification setting. However, the logs will show the errors.
Unfortunately, the question doesn't include enough details regarding the error that was mentioned.
